# How can I lay a circular region on my image in ds9?

Tags: region, astronomy, ds9

I'm working in ds9 and I need to make a circular region on my image. Everything I can find says I should be able to just left click with my mouse on the region I want the circle to be and a green circle will appear that I can then adjust. When I left click nothing happens! I've tried using my touch screen, doing this on a Mac, on Windows (my usual OS), but it's such a simple instruction I don't even know what else to try. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

lol I figured it out; if anyone else is having this problem make sure Region is selected on the Edit dropdown menu